Why is my svelte app runs on localhost but NOT on AWS Lightsail?
I have a Dockerized Svelte application that runs perfectly on my local machine, but I’m having trouble deploying it on AWS Lightsail. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Error

Log
[3/Jul/2024:08:42:00] [deployment:1] Creating your deployment
[3/Jul/2024:08:42:13] exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
[3/Jul/2024:08:43:02] [deployment:1] Started 1 new node
[3/Jul/2024:08:43:18] exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
[3/Jul/2024:08:44:13] [deployment:1] Started 1 new node
[3/Jul/2024:08:44:22] exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
[3/Jul/2024:08:45:27] [deployment:1] Started 1 new node
[3/Jul/2024:08:45:44] exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
[3/Jul/2024:08:46:02] [deployment:1] Canceled


Lightsail Container settings

Created a container service on Lightsail.
Added a container with the following details:

Container name: frontend
feed Image from ECR


Set the PUBLIC ENDPOINT to use port :3000.


Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build build/
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules node_modules/
COPY package.json .
EXPOSE 3000 # <--- I thought this would work
ENV NODE_ENV=production
CMD [ "node", "build" ]


Docker Desktop setup
When I run docker image on local machine, it will work without any issue.
I can access it from localhost:3000 or localhost if i change port to :80


Docker Desktop uses tcp, so i thought that was a reason why i had this issue, but I am not able to add :3000 tcp as Public Endpoint.
Update
I tested out with sveltekit app without any code modification (Skelton project). With Sveltkit dockerfile setup reference. So, i didn't have any env variable set on Lightsail.

EXPOSE 3000 # <--- I thought this would work FYI, the EXPOSE command in Docker doesn't do anything. It kind of only serves as documentation for other humans reading your file.

I have no experience of LightSail Container (have never used them), but have you somewhere told SvelteKit to listen to port 3000?

@PeppeL-G Thanks for comment, when I did the exactly same process with Linux, and everything worked as perfectly.

I tried with Mext.js and had the same issue. Turns out that the error:
exec format error

typically occurs when there is an architecture mismatch between the Docker image and the host machine. This can happen if the Docker image is built for one architecture (e.g., x86_64) and the host machine is running a different architecture (e.g., ARM64).
My MacOS was ARM64, while Lightsail was based on x86_64.
✅ I tried building the same image with my Ubuntu x86_64 and everyting worked as I expected.
I am going to wait for best answer since using Linux for pushing images isn't too realistic. For now, I am going to use linux since I am still struggling to figure  out how to create x86_64 image on ARM64 machine.
